# Is there any alternative library for jquery.dataTables.min.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery.dataTables.min.js plugin to get the entire table data in an object by using below method:

```
var nodes = $(".mastertable").dataTable().fnGetNodes(); // this will get my table data
```

However the dataTable() function is getting other elements on the table which I've been using in the whole project.

Does anyone have an alternative for jquery.dataTables.min.js plugin?

Comment: Datatables is by far the best table library. It would be more effective if you could give some details on your issues and we can suggest workarounds for them